# Switching between dev to prod mode does not generate all the required files in cache folder in symfony 4 project

Tags: php, symfony, caching, symfony4, production

while switching from DEV mode to PROD mode I noticed that some features in my symfony  project does not work well. I looked at my cache folder and i found that not all the required files are into prod folder.
I even restarted the server but the problem persists
I still ignore the reasons if it's not related to the server  whats the solution ?

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache? You have to put this command in the console. 
bin/console cache:clear
You may also need to add --env=prod in case the command only clears the dev cache.

Comment: Yes I tried that ! still does not work